# Implementing HashSet

Tags: scala

I have some weird compilation errors in my implementation of hash set. This code

```
class HashSet[A] extends scala.collection.mutable.Set[A] {
  override def +=(elem: A): HashSet[A] = {
    /* doing stuff */
    this
  }
}
```

produces the following errors

```
Error:(15, 16) overriding method += in trait SetLike of type (elem: A)HashSet.this.type;
 method += has incompatible type
  override def +=(elem: A): HashSet[A] = {
               ^
Error:(15, 16) overriding method += in trait Builder of type (elem: A)HashSet.this.type;
 method += has incompatible type
  override def +=(elem: A): HashSet[A] = {
               ^
Error:(15, 16) overriding method += in trait Growable of type (elem: A)HashSet.this.type;
 method += has incompatible type
  override def +=(elem: A): HashSet[A] = {
               ^
```

How can I fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are overriding is [`HashSet.+=`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashSet@+=(elem:A):HashSet.this.type), which has the following definition:

```
def +=(elem: A): HashSet.this.type
```

The return type is `HashSet.this.type`. You are overriding it with a method which returns a *different* type, `HashSet[A]`. That's not allowed.

In other words: mutating a mutable collection should not just return *any* collection of the same type, it should return the *exact same* collection (i.e. `this`). You are correctly returning `this` in your method, but you can make your return type more precise to explicitly state that you are not just returning *any* `HashSet`, you are returning *this* `HashSet`:

```
class HashSet[A] extends scala.collection.mutable.Set[A] {
  override def +=(elem: A):       this.type   = ???
  override def iterator:          Iterator[A] = ???
  override def -=(elem: A):       this.type   = ???
  override def contains(elem: A): Boolean     = ???
}
```

Since you are overriding a method with return type `this.type`, simply letting Scala infer the return type would have worked, too:

```
class HashSet[A] extends scala.collection.mutable.Set[A] {
  override def +=(elem: A)                    = ???
  override def iterator                       = ???
  override def -=(elem: A)                    = ???
  override def contains(elem: A)              = ???
}
```